# How to store value of constant from the closure in the variable of type String?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an app in which I am posting my post to Facebook from my app in which they provide me a postID now this postID is a constant and its in closure now I had to convert this postID in variable of type String and store that postID in my database. [image]

And when I print my result it shows like the below image I think this is a dictionary and I don't know how to convert it into string. If anyone can help.Below code used for posting:

```
if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil){
                if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("publish_actions") {
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: ["message": "Task: \(self.textField.text!)\n Task Description: \(self.textAreaDescription.text!)\n Time: \(self.dateTime)\n Location: \(self.placemark!.locality!) \(self.placemark!.administrativeArea!)"], HTTPMethod: "POST").startWithCompletionHandler({
                        (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        if (error != nil) {
                            // Do nothing
                        } else {
                            print("postID: \(result)")

                        }
                    })
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if let dic = result as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    let id = dic["id"]
}
```